# How to parametrize ArrayList properties without changing JAXB Web service schema or XML output?

Tags: java, arraylist, jaxb, wsdl, jaxb2

I have existing java application that is exposing interface via Web Services. I am trying to parametrize ArrayList properties without changing web service schema or result XML. For example, I am using class:

```
public class User {
    private ArrayList pricelists;

    public ArrayList getPricelists() { return pricelists; }
    public void setPricelists(ArrayList newPricelists) { this.pricelists = newPricelists; }
 }
```

When WSDL Schema is created from Java, result row looks like this:

```
<xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="pricelists" nillable="true" type="xs:anyType"/>
```

Now, when I parametrize ArrayList and add

```
private ArrayList<Pricelist> pricelists;
```

WSDL Schema looks like:

```
<xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="pricelists" nillable="true" type="tns:Pricelist"/>
```

I have managed to put it back by adding attribute:

```
@XmlSchemaType(name="anyType")
public ArrayList getPricelists() { return pricelists; }
```

Now we come to the problem. When objects are marshalled to XML, I get following XML:

```
<pricelists>
    <lastUpdate>1386659150085</lastUpdate>
    ...
</pricelists>
```

, instead of:

```
<pricelists xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="Pricelist">
    <lastUpdate>1386659150085</lastUpdate>
    ...
</pricelists>
```

How can I add that missing

```
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="Pricelist"
```

attributes with @XML... annotations? Is it possible to do it that way without writing personalized serializers?